# Uri.UriSchemeHttps equivalent in .NET core 1

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

Is there an equivalent to `Uri.UriSchemeHttps` in .NET Core 1? Is `Uri.Scheme` the new way to do it?

```
Uri myUri = new Uri("https://localhost:5000/login/");

Console.WriteLine(myUri.Scheme);
```

EDIT:
I added the following as a static member so I can use it in place of `Uri.UriSchemeHttps`. I need it to do a comparison with incoming request.

```
var httpsScheme = new Uri("https://www.google.com/").Scheme;
```

Comment: This field, as I understand, just contains string "https". What's a problem with just using this string instead?

Comment: @Evk, I did not realize all it contained was just `https`. I'll change it to that.